# Python Kivy select images from gallery

Tags: python, image, file-upload, kivy, android-gallery

Is it possible to load images from the gallery in a Kivy application?

On the Internet I found only a filechooser for all directories on the device. But I need a button, and when you click it, it opens menu where you select source. Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66uWZ.png).

Is it even possible on Kivy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day. The scope of your question is very big so I will give you the  highlights on what to do.

1. Find the directory path of pictures on your system device.
2. Under the FileChooser, set `rootpath = photos_directory_path`
3. For button: assign a [button callback](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html) method to open the filechooser at the directory. you could put the file chooser in a popup widget. Her is an example in kvlang

```
<FileChooserPopup@Popup>:
    FileChooser:
        rootpath:app.photos_directory_path

GridLayout: #your sliding-up interface
    Button:
        on_release: Factory.FileChooserPopup.open(root)
```